# Restore Database into MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, restore, mongorestore

I'm trying to restore a database into MongoDB, the command used is the following:
`mongorestore --db NewMonica dump\MonicaNew`

[image]

but I can't see the new database uploaded into Mongo DB as you can see in the link:
[image]

What can I do to restore the database in MongoDB?

Comment: based on your screens - seems that you restore locally, but check if it exist on remote server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, the command line option `--db` specifies the database to use when restoring from a BSON file.

Since you are restoring from a dump directory, that will have no effect.

You probably need to use one or more of `--nsInclude`, `--nsFrom`, `--nsTo`, or `--nsExclude`.

Comment: Thank you, Joe! I've tried the commands that you list, unfortunately they don't solve the issue

Comment: Look at the example in the documentation for restoring to a different database.